# Div shrinks when border is removed

Tags: html, css, format

I have a problem. I have the following layout at [This Weaver](http://liveweave.com/woShPm). (Make sure to view it fullscreen- the button is at the bottom right.)

My problem is this: when I change a border element(the border element in the .centered selector--around lines 238-240) the div appears to shrink around the content inside it. I have a background image, and it is there while the border exists, but then when you remove the border element, the image retracts as well.

For a better explanation, visit the Weaver above, and try removing line 239. See what happens. Unfortunately for me, I added that border for demonstrative purposes, and I need it removed, but what happens is unacceptable.

I need it to stay EXACTLY AS IS but WITHOUT the border(or if you could find a way to make it invisible and have the desired effect that works too). Please Help! If I'm not being clear enough please let me know, and I'll  make an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a border transparent via the `border-color` attribute:

```
.borderless { border-color: transparent; }
```

This can be shortened into a single line with other border related properties like so:

```
.borderless { border: 2px solid transparent; }
```

If you would prefer something you can transition smoothly to, consider [RGBA](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgba()) values:

```
.centered { border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); }
.borderless { border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); }
```

Any of these methods will maintain the layout, as the border is technically still present and taking up space. If you continue to find yourself having problems with layouts shifting unexpectedly on you, try looking into [box sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing):

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

will encourage layout elements to wrap borders in with their computed sizes and will make divisions behave in a fashion that's much more intuitive.

Comment: the box-sizing thing is great. In the past the problem that it solves has been incredibly problematic for me

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to do with [the box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html), and using padding vs. margin.

```
.s_container{
    margin-top: 20px;
    }
```

switch to:

```
.s_container{
    padding-top: 20px;
    }
```

and it seem to work fine on my machine.

To be honest, I don't don't really understand why adding/removing the border to the #configurator-container div would cause this behavior.

My understanding of the box model is that if you add a border, it's edge begins right where the padding left off. I'm confused by the large, 20px difference caused by the border's presence (as I know you are too).

Maybe one of our more experienced friends could explain this.